# SophosLabs Intelix - 16MB restriction

Tags: sophoslabs-intelix

According to the documentation and experiment with actual code, it is found that file larger than 16MB cannot be scanned by SophosLabs Intelix. Reference: https://api.labs.sophos.com/doc/changelog.html

Short video files, such as MP4, can usually be in the size of 100MB etc. It looks like such file types shall be processed by **Static Analysis**. What are the alternatives, given such restriction?

Attempted scanning a 50MB video and fails.

Answer (score 0):

A recent update to SophosLabs Intelix (13th March) has increased the maximum file size for both Static and Dynamic Analysis to 100Mb. The [changelog](https://api.labs.sophos.com/doc/changelog.html) referenced in the question now shows this.